# Event 'load' doesn't work on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events

I try to put an event on document loading but not works...
I'd put an alert box, but never seen it...

```
document.addEventListener ("load",initEventHandlers,false);

function initEventHandlers ()
{
document.getElementbyId ('croixzoom').addEventListener ('click',fermezoom,false);
alert ("Hello, i\'m a eventHAndlers")   
}
function fermezoom (){
document.getElementbyId ('zoom').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementbyId ('fondzoom').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document does not have an onload / load event, try attaching it to 'window':

```
window.addEventListener ("load",initEventHandlers,false);
```

Comment: this will not work because the DOM had not been loaded yet, so he can't use document.getElementById()...

Comment: The DOM does not need to be loaded in order to add an event to the window object!

Comment: I know
but in the code that Gayell wrote he accessed the DOM from the event handler, i think in this case the code will not work if the event hadler is fired for the load event of the window object

Comment: But you don't know where he has placed the script tag! If it's placed at the bottom of <body> then the function will work fine...

Comment: @Marwan: You're wrong: `window.onload` fires after the DOM has been built *and* external resources been loaded - that's the reason why there's `DOMContentLoaded` and all these `onready()` hacks: people don't want to wait for all images to be loaded before being able to modify the DOM...

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
window.onload = initEventHandlers;
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated** 
As a recomendation, not a direct solution to your problem: 
You might want to consider using a framework if you haven't already. 
Maybe look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com) which should take a lot of the pain out of what you are trying to do.

Then you could wrap it up in syntax like:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });
```

You might not want the additional layer on top of Javascript though.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Ah yes, the answer to everything 'use a framework'. That might help productivity but it won't help him learn how events work in Javascript will it?

Comment: learning how events work in javascript isn't all that useful (especially the cross browser differences) compared to a lightweight framework that does that for you.  but i gotta mark this down: people either forget, ignore or don't know theres a difference between ready() and load().

Comment: Events in javascript are fundamental. The cross browser problems aren't that complicated either. Perhaps we should all use GWT and forget javascript altogether?

Comment: Rory, fair enough it won't teach much about events in Javascript. Thats why I said 'You might want to consider using a framework' It's always good to get chastised for trying to be helpful I find.

Comment: Cletus, You're right I wasn't talking about document.onload ... but he's trying to use document.getElementbyId - which I unless he's injecting content would imply he wants manipulate the DOM. 
I was simply offering a potential alterntive to how he's doing things. It hardly warrants a mark down!